# Professional looking colors for iPhone UI

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Does someone has a list or some reference for using professional looking colors for iPhone UI (or view background) ?

Comment: Maybe try looking at popular color combinations on kuler.adobe.com?

Comment: Is this more towards iphone or general ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What looks "professional" is not only very subjective, it also depends on the context. Would you like to go for a discreet look or fancy ? What type of app are you developing ? For example, colors that would seem natural for a tea timer might not be suited for a notepad. So your question cannot be answered without details like what type of app you're developing, what interface concepts you'd like to use, which target audience you'd like to serve, etc. pp.

Comment: oh ok..i get ur point..I am looking for simple, but elegant looking colors..My app would fall in business/productivity category. Let me know if I need to add more info.

Comment: Have a look at sites like [ColorCombos](http://www.colorcombos.com/) or [Color Scheme Designer](http://colorschemedesigner.com/). While being targeted as web development, color scheme creation applies to "normal" UI development as well.

Answer (score 0):

Every application platform contains "platform characteristics" that set the standards for how an app should look, feel, and interact with the user. The only true way to get the colors and the ui that you are looking for, is to search the top apps in the iphone app store and draw comparisons between the top apps. Understand what colors are being used and in what way.

Learn from the trend-setting apps, imitate them or modify them as you see fit.

Hope this helped.